# Should I limit the amount I am connecting to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP application at the moment and I am writing a few validation rules for one of the models.

I have a feeling I am making too many checks to the database at the moment and want to get a view on this.

For example I am saving to a model which has a lot of associated models as such I am saving 5 different foreign id's per save operation. To ensure that all of the id's are correct I have a validation rule for each which checks that in fact the ID does exist in the correct table in the database.

There are also a few other validation rules, but without going in to too much detail I think I am hitting the database around 10 times for one save operation, to ensure that all of the data is valid.

Is there any sort of limit I should be applying, or is the overhead fairly minimal?

Thanks

Comment: Without specifics, it is hard to say either way.

Comment: It's considered generally good to get as much information as possible over to PHP and store it, then you'll be able to do operations without contacting the dtaabase every time.

Comment: doing to many sql queries may slow down your loading time :S what truth said is the approach i will suggest. Or at least try doing them in the same transaction. you have 2 options either bring all the ids and a in_array() or do some verifications in the db (constraints) if error cake won't save and you'll get a false from the save function... and you may display an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Get your app rolled out. Once real people use it for real purposes, you can do benchmarks to see where you really need to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

If the connections you establish are for good reason (and validations are pretty high up there) then it would be okay to connect as you must. However, is it not possible to put these validations together? Are you using stored procedures? If you do, then it would be possible to put the batch of validations together in one stored procedure. It's almost like saying run as many validation rules as you can together in one go, then expect multiple result sets (if needed --and this would be better in some ways than to simply return false when one validation fails but of course that depends on the dependencies of these validations)

To shorten my post.. Would it be possible to put these validation queries together in one stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

check that your database is properly designed. With limited information you provided its difficult to judge if you really need to go through all tables or not. But typically you would not need to do it.

Also hitting a database unnecessarily is not such a good idea. It all depends on your application. If you dont really need a very high performance application you may be ok. The overhead for reads would not be as bad as the database would do some memory caching. Writes will always be more expensive. Especially if you have foreign key constraints. As the db will check if the write is valid.

Best way is to write a test which tries to write "x" records in the database via your logic and time it. That will give you an indication if it is really an issue at all.